# Ouput link to show User Page

Tags: visualforce, outputlink

```
   lstUser = [SELECT    Id,ContactId, Contact.Name
                    FROM    user 
                    WHERE   IsActive=true 
                    AND     IsPortalEnabled = true
                    AND     contact.accountId = : account.Id 
                    AND     contactId != null
                    AND     Id != :user.Id];

            for(User u: lstUser)
            {
                contactIds.add(u.ContactId);
            }

             lstContact=[Select Name,AccountId from Contact where Id IN: contactIds ORDER BY Name Asc];


<apex:repeat value="{!lstcontact}" var="contact">
            <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Name}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:outputlink title="User Details" value="{!contact.Name}">User Details</apex:outputlink>

            <hr style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"/>
        </apex:repeat>
```

On clicking on User details i want the it to redirect to the User Details Page... can i pass the id of user of that contact to the outputlink.
This link is not working.

Comment: Just to clarify, your page is running in the customer portal. And the link you require is a link to the Salesforce "User" Details Page linked with the Contact, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The Portal user licenses do not have access to the user object.  The best you could do would be to show their own contact record details instead.  One thing I have done in the past is created an trigger that sync'd fields from the contact record to the user record. This allowed the portal user to make basic changes (address, phone,title,etc) to their contact record, which would then update their User record.
I am not certain why you want to show the user record, but if it is to allow access to update, then this is certainly a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pass contact.id,
`<apex:outputlink title="User Details" value="{!contact.id}">User Details</apex:outputlink>`

This should work for you.

Comment: hey thanks Rahul..  2 points over here                                                     1. Its working if am using a vf page outside customer portal. As i am using customer portal i am not able to view the contact details page.                                                      2. I want the show the user page of that contact. As contact is a portal user.

Comment: Check this link..this might helpful for you..
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_customer_portal.htm&language=en_US...  Please mark it as answer if it works for you for future reference of other users.

Comment: No much of help

Comment: https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_customer_portal_implementation_guide.pdf   ...Check page number 19